# WPF: reverting brush to default/original

Tags: wpf, user-controls, default

I'm a complete newbie at WPF.

At the moment I'm making a usercontrol for form elements called "LabeledTextbox" which contains a label, a textbox and a textblock for errormessages.

When the using code adds an errormessage, I want to put the border of the textbox in red. But, when the errormessage gets removed, I'd like to turn back to the default bordercolor of the textbox. 
I feel there must be a very easy way to do this.

My code:

*(in public partial class LabeledTextbox : UserControl)*

```
public string ErrorMessage
{
    set
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            _textbox.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black; //How do I revert to the original color in the most elegant way?
        }
        else
        {
            _textbox.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
        }

        _errorMessage.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You could use

```
_textBox.ClearValue(TextBox.BorderBrushProperty);
```

That will remove the directly assigned value and go back to the value defined by the style or template.

Comment: great, thanks!
*adds dependencyproperty research to the to-do list*

Comment: Thanks, very helpful article. I tried storing the default brush by the brush.clone method but according to .net no brush exists when its system default. Thank you!

Comment: This didn't work for me. I set background to Aquamarine when I want to draw attention to it. I tried to use the ClearValue to revert it back but it stayed as Aquamarine.  Looking at this post: ( http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/clearvalue/) told me that ClearValue reverts it back to the last assigned value. So I tried setting the Background property to Nothing and it worked. The label background was now the default color.

Answer (score 16):

You can grab the default colours from the class **SystemColors**

Here is the list of **all system colours**:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx

Default **background colour** of the client area:

```
     _textbox.Background = SystemColors.WindowBrush;
```

Default **text colour** inside the client area:

```
     _textbox.SystemColors.WindowTextBrush
```

Comment: This answer is useful in MVVM environment. There I cannot clear the BorderBrushProperty as in the otherwise good answer by Daniel. But setting a controls´ background to its default brush works by returning the brush explicitly in a property on the viewmodel.

Answer (score 5):

I may be late to the party, but for future readers, you can also use `Button.BackgroundProperty.DefaultMetadata.DefaultValue` for this purpose. This is especially useful when you're using a Converter where you need to **return a value** and therefore cannot use `ClearValue()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? Setting it to black is better than using the ClearValue method

```
public string ErrorMessage
{
    set
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            _textbox.Background = Brushes.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            _textbox.Background = Brushes.Red;
        }

        _errorMessage.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: oh sorry, I made a mistake in my post. It doesn't because the default is a gradient color.

Comment: @Thomas Stock :0 Never tested it. So also sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the default settings. Here a code excample.

```
        System.Windows.Media.Brush save;

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {
          //Store the default background 
        save = testButton.Background;

        }


        private void ChangeBackground(){

        testButton.Background = Brushes.Red;

        }

        private void restoreDefaultBackground(){

        //Restore default Backgroundcolor

        testButton.Background = save;

        }
```