# Default foreground color of ProgressBar

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, systemcolors, system.windows.media

I've been changing the foreground color of the `ProgressBar` control from my C# code using the `Brush` and `Brushes` classes from the `System.Windows.Media` library. However, I'm wondering if .Net provides access to the original default foreground color of the `ProgressBar` for when I want to revert back.

Example:

[image]

Right now I'm referencing an answer provided by @Beauty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306499/wpf-reverting-brush-to-default-original) that uses the [SystemColors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.systemcolors(v=vs.100).aspx) class. `SystemColors` seems to be the .Net class that provides the default brush colors of controls, but I don't see a brush for the foreground of a `Progressbar`. Is this color obtainable in `SystemColors`, or is there some other way of getting it?

An example of how I am changing colors:

XAML:

```
<ProgressBar Name="Progress" Foreground="{Binding LoadScreenModel.BarColor}" />
```

C#:

```
private Brush _barColor = Brushes.Red;

public Brush BarColor
{
    get { return _barColor; }
    set
    {
        _barColor = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => BarColor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default style for the `ProgressBar` control (found on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815175/wpf-progressbar-style) and you can get it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa972144(v=vs.90).aspx)) reveals that the foreground color by default is:

> #FF01D328

That may well match up with a system color, but otherwise just use that.